# How to change width of card in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

do you have any tips how to change width of card please?

I tried SizedBox Card but it didnt work as well. It only changed height.

Here is my code below

```
body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 3.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 50, 50, 50),
              leading: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: 150,
                  minHeight: 150,
                  maxWidth: 150,
                  maxHeight: 150,
                ),
                child: Image.asset('assets/yeme_logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
              trailing: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                size: 27.0,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage your `Card's width and height like:

```dart
/// Change your [Padding] widget with container.
Container(
  height: 50, 
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,

  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: (...) // Here your child
```

**Full Code:**

```dart
Container(
  height: 50, //
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Card(
    elevation: 3.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
    child: ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 50, 50, 50),
      leading: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: 150,
          minHeight: 150,
          maxWidth: 150,
          maxHeight: 150,
        ),
        child: Image.asset('assets/yeme_logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
        size: 27.0,
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I tried it, but only height changed. Is it because i have it in ListView?

Comment: this Card is in `ListView`? if is it can you update your question and add ListView code

Comment: its updated. but i only wanna change that one card in listview.

Comment: You can do that with wraping container, wrap your Card widget with Container and give some heigh and width values

Answer (score -1):

Height & width of the card can be set using below code:

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  child: Card()
)
```

You can also set the dimensions of size according to device's screen size:

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context). size. width,
child: Card()
)
```

Let me know if you are facing any other issues.